# Rails 3 link_to partial with for loop inside

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I've never programmed before and am having difficulty getting `link_to` to render the corresponding `:partial` in a users' profile inside of my Rails 3 app. All in all there are three partials:

1. _profile_credits (*I'm focusing on `_profile_credits` for the sake of this question.*)
2. _profile_about
3. _profile_reviews

What I want to do is click the following:

```
<li><%= link_to "Credits", profile_credits_profile_path(:id => @profile.id), :remote => true %></li>
```

And have the following partial (_profile_credits) load and render each credit in @user.credits:

```
<% for credit in @user.credits %>
  <div class="credit">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Where I'm trying to render the partial is beneath the links and inside of the div container. The HTML below shows the position of the links within the div and where I'd like the info from the partials to load:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><%= link_to "Reviews", profile_reviews_profile_path(:id => @profile.id), :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "About", profile_about_profile_path(:id => @profile.id), :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Credits", profile_credits_profile_path(:id => @profile.id), :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    ##load information from the partials inside `<div id="tabs-1">
  </div>
</div><!-- end tabs -->
```

And the rest of my code...

My `profiles_controller#profile_credits` action:

```
def profile_credits
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

In my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :profiles do
  get :profile_credits, :on => :member
end
```

My `profile_credits.js.erb`:

```
$( "#tabs" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render (:partial => "profile_credits", :locals => { :id => @profile.id } ) ) %>" );
```

At the moment nothing happens when I click a link. I've tried following the various Rails 3 UJS examples but can't get it. At one point I specified more in the ProfilesController `profile_credits` action. However, if I was on someone else's profile my credits were loading, not the credits of the user whose profile I was browsing. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Since you say you've never programmed before, I'll bring this up.  Don't use arbitrary variable names for anything other extremely simple purposes (like `i` as an iterator).  Part of the reason this hasn't been answered is likely because it's hard for anyone to guess what's going on given actions named `a` and partials named `c`.  What are these things?

Comment: Gotcha, they are credits. I named it that way to keep my URL shorter but probably shouldn't let that dictate how I name controller actions and partials.

Comment: I've put the full action names in for your reference. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your profile_credits partial refers to `@user`, and you are passing `@profile.id` in to it as a local. So what is the relationship between `@user` and `@profile`? Do you have a **User** model or is `@user` just an instance variable from the profile_controller? What ties `@user` and `@profile` together? Perhaps you mean to refer to `@profile` inside your profile_credits partial?

Comment: I have models for `User` and `Profile`. User `has_one :profile`. Profile `belongs_to :user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this to work. Given a `<div>` that contains a `<ul>` navigation and a `<div>` for the loaded content, here is my code:

**HTML for my container:**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul id="infoContainer">
    <li><%= link_to "Reviews", profile_reviews_profile_path, :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "About", profile_about_profile_path, :remote => true %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Credits", profile_credits_profile_path, :remote => true %></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <%= render :partial 'profile_reviews %> #default
  </div>
</div><!-- end tabs -->
```

**`_profile_credits.html.erb` partial:**

```
<% for credit in @user.credits %>
  <div class="credit">
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**`profile_credits.js.erb`:**

```
$( "#tabs-1" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript( render (:partial => "profile_credits" ) ) %>" );
```

**`profile_credits.rb` controller:**

```
def profile_credits
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(@profile.user_id)
  @credits = User.find(@profile.id).credits
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => nil }
    format.xml
    format.js { render :layout => nil }
  end
end
```

That did it.